# Breaking down a image url into three sub parts in PHP

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-match

Suppose I have this image URL:
http://static2.tripoto.com/media/filter/medium/img/11099/TripDocument/chiang_mai_street_market.jpg

I want to extract 3 things from this url:

- "medium" (This can be medium/small/thumbnail)
- the part after medium and before the image name (img/11099/TripDocument)
- image name (chiang_mai_street_market.jpg)

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: Have a look at http://php.net/manual/fr/function.pathinfo.php

Comment: @Cr3aHal0 I have tried pathinfo, but i am not getting the desired output from it.
I get this when I run it on the url i have given:
dirname: http://static2.tripoto.com/media/filter/medium/img/11099/TripDocument
basename:
chiang_mai_street_market.jpg

Comment: Do you always know how deep is the medium/small/thumbnail folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also You can use regular expression, if You want:

```
preg_match_all('/^.*(medium|small|thumbnail)\/(.*)\/([^\/]+)$/', $url, $matches);
```

Result:

- $matches[0] = $url
- $matches[1] = "medium"
- $matches[2] = "img/11099/TripDocument"
- $matches[3] = "chiang_mai_street_market.jpg"

Assumption:

- There is none other "medium", "small", or "thumbnail" string in given url, before that You need.

**Edit:**

To make it more flexible fot another sizes/phrases, You could extract phrases to another array, like this:

```
$sizes = ['medium', 'small', 'thumbnail'];

preg_match_all('/^.*(' . implode('|', $sizes ) . ')\/(.*)\/([^\/]+)$/', $url, $matches);
```

Comment: This works. Thanx. Do you know any site to learn how to build regex?

Comment: It would be better if we could break the expression from "filter" to make it indepedent of medium/thumbnail/small, because there may be other sizes too

Comment: Can't recommend any site. There are documentations like http://pcre.org/pcre.txt, but it's not very friendly.

Comment: Can't we match the word "filter" and then get the size. i.e get the phrase until next backslash. So we wont need an array of sizes in that case

Comment: got it `^.*(filter)\/([^\/]+)\/(.*)\/([^\/]+)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this 2 ways.

1.pathinfo function - http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

2.using `explode` with delimiter `/` and working on with the arrays from there.

The second one is not recommended though.

Comment: I have tried pathinfo, but i am not getting the desired output from it.
I get this when I run it on the url i have given:
dirname: http://static2.tripoto.com/media/filter/medium/img/11099/TripDocument
basename:
chiang_mai_street_market.jpg

Comment: You can probably go using `explode` then.